# Emacs Evil-mode key rebinding

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, evil-mode

How do I rebind

`1` as `4` and `4` as `6` without `1` becoming `6`?

Comment: What did you try so far ? And what do you want to do ?

Comment: Can you give us a working example that exhibits the undesired behavior? In Emacs you bind keys to functions, *not* to other keys, so the 'transitive' binding that make `noremap` necessary in Vimscript doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear at all. What do you want to achieve ?

If you want to insert "4" when you press 1:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "1") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "4")))
(global-set-key (kbd "4") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "6")))
```